# Browse oldfiles list length

Tags: gvim, file-operations

I use `:browse oldfiles` command to open recent files quickly. The list becomes very long with time -- I have 100 items in the list and need to tap space to complete this action. I want to reduce this list or show only last 10-20 items.

- How to set the limit for the history of opened files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:browse oldfiles` and `:oldfiles` read from the viminfo file, so changing the maximum number of previously edited files to be remembered in the `'viminfo'` option should work.  You can do this by changing the number after the `'` character in the viminfo option.

For example, doing `:set viminfo='50` would mean that only 50 old files are remembered.

However, this will overwrite everything currently set in the the `'viminfo'` option, so make sure to set the other desired options as well.  For example, doing `:set viminfo='50,<50,s10,h` would also mean that the maximum number of lines saved for each register would be 50, the maximum size of saved items is 10 KB and the effect of `'hlsearch'` is disabled when loading the viminfo file.

For more on this topic, see `:help 'viminfo'`.

**NOTE:** You may need to wipe your viminfo file before the change will take effect, since all of your old files past your max number will be remembered still.

Comment: note the leading apostrophe